# Who is tampering with my data stream?

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

The piece of code below downloads a file from some URL and saves it to a local file. Piece of cake. What could possible be wrong here?

```
protected long download(ProgressMonitor montitor) throws Exception{
    long size = 0;
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
    while( (read = dis.read(chunk)) != -1){
        os.write(chunk, 0, read);
        size += read;
        if(montitor != null)
            montitor.worked(read);
    }

    chunk = null;
    dis.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return size;
}
```

The reason I am posting a question here is because it works in 99.999% of the time and doesn't work as expected whenever there is an antivirus or some other protection software installed on a computer running this code. I am blindly pointing a finger that way because whenever I stop (or disable) it, the code works perfect again. The end result of such interference is that the MD5 of downloaded file don't match the expected, and a whole new saga begins.

So, the question is - is it really possible that some smart "protection" software would alter the actual stream coming from the URL without me knowing about it? And if yes - how do you deal with this? (*verified with Kasperksy and Norton products*).

---

**EDIT-1:**
Apparently I've got a hold on the problem and it's got nothing to do with antiviruses. The download takes place from the FTP server (FileZilla in particular) and we use apache commons ftp on client side . What I did is went to the FTP server and terminated the connection (kicked it out) in a middle of the download. I expected that is.read(..) would throw an IOException on client side, but this never happened. Instead, the is.read(..) returns -1 meaning that there is no more data coming from the stream. This is definitely unexpected and explains why sometimes I get partial files. This doesn't explain however why sometimes the data gets altered as well.

Comment: How do you handle exeptions? If `dis.close()` throws exception the output stream will not close properly for example.

Comment: @dacwe - whatever thrown from this method is a failure, everything gets aborted. The mystery is that nothing gets thrown, everything gets downloaded just fine. The problem is that it's not the data I expect, most of the time it's cut in half, sometimes altered..

Comment: @EJP - replaced to "doesn't work as expected"

Comment: put a `try { } catch(Exception) {e.printStackTrace();}` arround your method body and tell us, what is printed out in case of failure.

Comment: @brimborium - as I said, nothing is thrown, I would know how to deal with it otherwise. I simply get wrong stuff.

Comment: Define "wrong". Is part of the content just shifted a few bits, is everything zero from a certain point on, or is it just random bits (or do you see a certain pattern in there)?

Comment: @brimborium - I didn't investigate that into the bits yet. This method is part of version update, it downloads the installer and runs it. But before installer is launched I verify integrity of downloaded part - it's size is wrong, and obviously the MD5 checksum is wrong. Where and how it's wrong is not an issue right now. What strikes me is why this would happen in the first place - is it my bug? or I don't know something? Whenever the third party software is turned off - everything works again. And how one should know if nothing is thrown..

Comment: @Dima: You could have silently ignored the exception (it's not in the code/question above)

Comment: @dacwe - nope, the caller of this method will abort anything and halt on error, i didn't want to post to much irrelevant code

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and "as expected". You aren't providing enough information here. What does it do instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this happens to me all the time. In my case it's caused by transparent HTTP proxying by Websense on my corporate network. The worst problem are caused by the block page being returned with 200 OK.

Do you get the same or similar corruption every time? E.g., do you get some HTML explaining why the request was blocked? The best you can probably do is compare the first few bytes of the downloaded data to some text in the block page, and throw an exception in this case.

Edit: based on your update, have you got the FTP client set to image/binary mode?

Comment: In my case it's not a text, I would have noticed what exactly gets tampered. I download binary installation package, so it's hard to tell what part of it is blasted. End result is a corrupted binary and total confusion of end users which point a finger at me when it actually is something which sits on their network.

Comment: You need to write out the incorrect bytes to disk and have a look at them.